# Error ORA-00933 on create editioning view

Tags: oracle, view

I'm trying to create an editioning view in Oracle 11g and it's giving the error "ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended", I ran it with the owner of schema and sys, but the error persists.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONING VIEW "CEGASV3"."VE_COML_FACTIVEL"(
    "PK_FACTIVEL", "FACTIVEL", "ENDERECO", "NOMECONTATO", "TELCONTATO01", "TELCONTATO02", 
    "EMAIL", "SEGMENTO", "DT_DIGIT", "RESPONSAVEL", "INFOUTEIS", "NOME_TABELA_HISTORICO", 
    "DATA_HORA","VPD_GEMPI","ORA_GEOMETRY","ORA_GEOMETRY_GOOGLE","STATUS" 
) AS 
SELECT F.PK_FACTIVEL, F.FACTIVEL, F.ENDERECO, F.NOMECONTATO, F.TELCONTATO01, F.TELCONTATO02, 
F.EMAIL, F.SEGMENTO, F.DT_DIGIT, F.RESPONSAVEL, F.INFOUTEIS, F.NOME_TABELA_HISTORICO, 
F.DATA_HORA, F.VPD_GEMPI, F.ORA_GEOMETRY, F.ORA_GEOMETRY_GOOGLE, F.STATUS
FROM CEGASV3.COML_FACTIVEL F   
LEFT JOIN CEGASV3.COML_PROSPECT P ON P.FK_FACTIVEL = F.PK_FACTIVEL   
WHERE P.PK_PROSPECT IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create complex view as editioning view. It means you can not use multiple tables as a query of the view, It must be a single table view.

> Editioning views are a wrapper over the base table. It can only be a
> straight query of the base table, but can display a subset of the
> columns and give alias to them.

Read more about editioning view [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/edition-based-redefinition-11gr2#editioning_views).